# Java sockets - How to simulate multiple clients

Tags: java, sockets, distributed-computing

I have a socket program written in Java.

The server makes use of DatagramSocket to create a socket with a particular port number. I have a client java program, which connects to this server and sends some messages.

Currently I have 3 laptops so I use 1 to run the server and the remaining 2 to be clients. How can I simulate 100 clients?

I am thinking of writing a wrapper around the clients and call them 100 times, but the problem is with the ip-address for those simulated clients *NOT* being unique. Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need unqiue IP Address?

Comment: Here is the thing, Route and process every incoming request on new Thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the problem is with the ip-address for those simulated clients NOT being unique

No, the problem is that you are only *identifying* clients by their IP address. You should use IP:port, for example, via `DatagramSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress().`

Then you can test by running 100 instances of your client program in a single host.

Answer (score 3):

I would say use JMeter http://jmeter.apache.org/

TCP sampler:
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler

You can call Java directly: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request

Comment: Will JMeter not use the same IP address for each client connection? The OP stated in his question that he wants a unique IP to be used for each client.